# Почему объект отображается как <__main__.Restaurant object at 0x0042DE90>?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-faq

Начал только изучать классы в Python и столкнулся с такой проблемой(или нет) что при выводе результата первой строкой идёт:

```
<__main__.Restaurant object at 0x0042DE90>
```

Меня это начало интересовать, но ответа на просторах интернета не нашёл, поэтому надеюсь что знатоки помогут.
Вот весь код для прояснения вопроса:

```
class Restaurant:

   def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
       self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
       self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type

   def describe_restaurant(self):
       print(self.restaurant_name)
       print(self.cuisine_type)

  def open_restaurant(self):
       print(self.restaurant_name+' is open!')


my_rest = Restaurant('Clot monet', 'classical')
print(my_rest)
my_rest.describe_restaurant()
my_rest.open_restaurant()
```

OUTPUT:

```
<__main__.Restaurant object at 0x0042DE90>
Clot monet
classical
Clot monet is open!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Потому что любой непосредственно запускаемый питоном файл является модулем `__main__`, и класс `Restaurant` создан внутри модуля `__main__`

Comment: @andreymal , не совсем понял в чём ошибка, можете 'разжевать' ?) А точнее как убрать эту строчку исправив сам код

Comment: О какой ошибке речь? Здесь всё в порядке, проблем нет

Comment: @Arsen_Aganesov, почему вы решили что это ошибка? Это описание объекта вашего класса. Если хотите свое показывать, то переопределите метод `__str__` у вашего класса, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/stepik_lesson/course_512/24473_step_4/main.py#L63 , https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/compassplus_employees/db.py#L122

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самое главное: это не ошибка. Это просто стандартный способ вывода объекта, если в нем не переопределены методы `__repr__` и `__str__`.

`__main__` - это просто название текущего запущенного модуля (тот самый `__main__`, с которым идет сравнение в конструкциях `if __name__ == "__main__":`). Для классов из импортируемых модулей вместо `__main__` будет отображаться имя файла без `.py`.

При печати любого объекта он сначала конвертируется в строку, потом уже печатается. Конвертация происходит с помощью методов [`__repr__` или `__str__`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/953904/1365) объектов:

```
class Test:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "repr"

    def __str__(self):
        return "str"


# В первую очередь используется __str__:
print(Test())  # Вывод: str
print(str(Test()))  # Вывод: str
print(repr(Test()))  # Вывод: repr

print()


class Test:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "repr"


# Если метод __str__ не переопределен, то используется __repr__:
print(Test())  # Вывод: repr
print(str(Test()))  # Вывод: repr
print(repr(Test()))  # Вывод: repr
# Т.е. print(объект) по сути то же самое что print(str(объект))
```

Если вы в своем классе эти методы не добавляете, то будут использоваться соответствующие методы из класса `object`, а он конвертирует в строку именно в таком виде `<модуль.ИмяКласса object at Адрес>`.

Таким образом, это стандартное repr-представление объекта, унаследованное от object.

Как исправить - переопределить метод `__repr__` (и/или `__str__`) в своем классе:

```
class Restaurant:
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print(self.restaurant_name)
        print(self.cuisine_type)

    def open_restaurant(self):
        print(self.restaurant_name+' is open!')
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}(restaurant_name={!r}, cuisine_type={!r})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.restaurant_name, self.cuisine_type)


my_rest = Restaurant('Clot monet', 'classical')
print(my_rest)
my_rest.describe_restaurant()
my_rest.open_restaurant()
```

Вывод:

```
Restaurant(restaurant_name='Clot monet', cuisine_type='classical')
Clot monet
classical
Clot monet is open!
```

---

#### Зачем вообще нужны целых два методы для преобразования объекта в строку?

Вкратце:

- `repr` представление - это удобное представление объекта для программиста, оно обычно содержит внутреннюю техническую информацию об объекте. Например, то же стандартное `repr` представление вида `<модуль.ИмяКласса object at Адрес>`.

  Часто делают, чтобы `repr` представление было валидным кодом на Python, и его можно было скопировать в код, чтобы создался объект с нужным содержимым, как `Restaurant(restaurant_name='Clot monet', cuisine_type='classical')` в примере выше.

  `repr` представление отображается при использовании функции `repr` (или при конвертации в строку, если не переопределен метод `__str__`, но переопределен `__repr__`), и в интерактивном режиме Python.
- `str` представление - представление для пользователя программы. Пользователю не нужны внутренние детали реализации, нужен просто текст.

Еще, на примере объекта даты-времени: для программиста будет удобен вид отображения `datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 10, 11, 25, 3)` (чтобы знать что это за объект, и как его создать), а пользователю нужна только сама дата-время, ему нужно будет показать `2019-03-10 11:25:03`. Пример взят из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/953904/1365).

Comment: Добавить бы ещё в ответ, зачем нужен `__repr__`, когда он используется (интерактивный python, например).

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. О, интересные подробности, кое-что не знал

Answer (score 0):

Суть непонимания предыдущих комментаторов в том, что они на самом деле не видят ошибки в том, что вы написали, потому что ошибки и нет. Вы прямо просите напечатать объект экземпляра класса, и он выводит эти данные такой вот служебной информацией.

чтобы этого избежать в вашем случае, просто не надо писать  print(my_rest)

```
    my_rest = Restaurant('Clot monet', 'classical')
    #print(my_rest)
    my_rest.describe_restaurant()
    my_rest.open_restaurant()
```

Моя же проблема была в том, что я принтил метод класса `print(Class.classmetod(arg))`.
В конструкторе метода был указан свой print
И мне помимо правильного ответа выдавалась еще эта "служебная информация" `__main__` и т.д.
В моем случае надо было в методе класса писать не просто return, а еще параметр объекта класса указывать

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data   
        
    @classmethod    
    def extract (cls, data_1):
        new_str = data_1.split('-')
        for i in range(0, len(new_str)):
            new_str[i] = int(new_str[i])
        return cls(tuple(new_str)).data

    print(Data.extract('25-12-2004'))
```

Вот этого выделенного `.data` у меня не было, и был `print(self.data)` в конструкторе

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data   
        print(self.data)
    @classmethod    
    def extract (cls, data_1):
        new_str = data_1.split('-')
        for i in range(0, len(new_str)):
            new_str[i] = int(new_str[i])
        return cls(tuple(new_str))

    print(Data.extract('25-12-2004'))
```

И ответ был вот таким

```
(25, 12, 2004)
<__main__.Data object at 0x0000012A9357BFD0>
```

Потому что по факту происходило 2 вещи:

1. мне выдавался ответ из конструктора
2. печатался мой принт, в которые по факту передавался объект экземпляра класса, он и давал эту `__main__.Data object at 0x0000012A9357BFD0`

В общем, объяснил как смог. Мне бы пригодилась написанная мной портянка, вдруг поможет кому-то)

Comment: а че кто минусанул ответ? что не понравилось то? хочется знать что в этом ответе не так

Comment: Действительно, непонятно. Восстановил справедливость голосом за.