# Так что делает специальный метод __repr__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Прошу помощи в понимании специального метода `__repr__`. Книга говорит, что он присутствует в объекте для вывода на экран переменных. Если под переменными подразумеваются значения атрибутов в данном объекте, то этим занимается метод `__str__`.

И ещё: что значит преобразовать объект в строку?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Преобразовать объект в строку - значит представить в виде строки всю значимую информацию, которая необходима для того, чтобы воссоздать этот объект. Это не какая-то универсальная процедура, каждый программист сам выбирает, каким образом лучше это сделать. Подробнее вы можете погуглить по слову "сериализация".

Comment: You can read about this there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984162/purpose-of-pythons-repr.

Answer (score 3):

[`__repr__(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) - вызывается встроенной функцией [repr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr); возвращает "сырые" данные, использующиеся для внутреннего представления в `python`.

[`__str__(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) - вызывается функциями [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str), [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) и [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format). Возвращает строковое представление объекта.

---

Хороший пример использования этих магических методов:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 10, 11, 25, 3)
print(str(today))   # 2019-03-10 11:25:03
print(repr(today))  # datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 10, 11, 25, 3)
```

---

Можно только `__str__` переопределить, показывая человеко-читаемое строковое представление объекта, а `__repr__` оставить дефолтным, в котором будет показан тип объекта и его адрес.

Пример:

```
class MyPoint:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return f'<MyPoint(x={self.x}, y={self.y})>'

p = MyPoint(1, 1)
print(p)        # <MyPoint(x=1, y=1)>
print(str(p))   # <MyPoint(x=1, y=1)>
print(repr(p))  # <__main__.MyPoint object at 0x000001D8284001D0>
```

По умолчанию, `__str__` возвращает значение из `__repr__`:

```
class MyPoint:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

p = MyPoint(1, 1)
print(p)        # <__main__.MyPoint object at 0x000001D8284001D0>
print(str(p))   # <__main__.MyPoint object at 0x000001D8284001D0>
print(repr(p))  # <__main__.MyPoint object at 0x000001D8284001D0>
```

Поэтому, если переопределить только `__repr__`, то оба будут возвращать одно и тоже:

```
class MyPoint:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<MyPoint(x={self.x}, y={self.y})>'

p = MyPoint(1, 1)
print(p)        # <MyPoint(x=1, y=1)>
print(str(p))   # <MyPoint(x=1, y=1)>
print(repr(p))  # <MyPoint(x=1, y=1)>
```

Comment: что значит строковое представление обьекта, если, по моему представлению, обьект это набор атрибутов и методов. Как можно это всё каким-то образом представить в виде одной строки. Может быть, что-то не так с моим пониманием обьектов как таковых.

Comment: @СергейБалко, нет никакого универсального стандарта. Каждый программист, создающий свой класс, и переопределяющий для него методы str и repr, отталкивается исключительно от своего представления о том, какая информация по данному объекту будет полезна для вывода. Разделение на то, что str - это человекочитаемое представление, а repr - более "техническое" представление, является всего лишь рекомендацией, разумной для большинства случаев, но не обязательной.